# pyplot missing first event after first show/close of figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, imshow

I'm trying to iterate through a series of images in a matplotlib figure, and record a series of events (mouse clicks and key presses) for each image. However, after the first figure the first event is getting missed.

For instance, in the following MLE if the user presses 'q' after the first image is displayed the second image is then displayed. However if the user then presses 'q' again the event is missed and they have to press 'q' a third time before the second image is closed.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show, draw

class guiBackend:
  def __init__(self, srcImage):

    self.srcImage = srcImage
    self.fig = figure(figsize=(16,16), frameon=False)
    self.axSrc = self.fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=True)
    self.showObj = self.axSrc.imshow(self.srcImage)

    self.cidKey = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.pressButton)

  def pressButton(self, event):
    if event.key == 'q':
      self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidKey)
      plt.close(self.fig)
      return
    else:
      self.srcImage = random.randint(0, 256, size=(128,128,3))
      self.showObj.set_data(self.srcImage)
      self.fig.canvas.draw()


def main():

  for k in xrange(2):
    img = random.randint(0, 256, size=(128,128,3))
    imgObj = guiBackend(img)
    plt.show()

  return 1
```

From what I've gathered this is due to multiple calls to `show()` and `close()` but I can't figure out another way to block the program during each iteration of the loop in order collect the series of user input until the user presses 'q'.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this problem (missing events) running (sort of) the 1.5.x branch.  As for your second question, I suggest injecting the loop into the gui handling code via a generator:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class guiBackend:
    def __init__(self, img_gen):

        self.img_gen = iter(img_gen)
        self.cur_image = next(self.img_gen)

        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16), frameon=False)
        self.axSrc = self.fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=True)
        self.im = self.axSrc.imshow(self.cur_image)

        self.cidKey = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',
                                                  self.button_press)

    def button_press(self, event):
        print("in handler")
        print('got key {}'.format(event.key))
        if event.key == 'q':
            try:
                self.cur_image = next(self.img_gen)
            except StopIteration:
                plt.close(self.fig)
                return
            self.im.set_data(self.cur_image)
            self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()


def image_gen(n):
    for k in range(n):
        yield np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(128, 128, 3))
# need to hold on to this or callback gets gc'd
gui_backend = guiBackend(image_gen(5))
plt.show()
```